# Nodejs query inside for loop returns blank array

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, for-loop

here is my nodejs code to get result of query inside for loop.
I tried many things but it can not work it always return blank array
any one can help me. thanks

```
var venueId = req.query.venueId;
var month = req.query.month;

var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var count = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

var datacounts = [];
for (var d = 1; d <= count; d++) {
    var gDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + d;
    connection.query("SELECT count(created_at) as count FROM guest_going_venues where DATE(created_at) = ? AND venue_id = ? GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY DATE(created_at) ASC",
        [gDate, venueId], (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (!err) {
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    var gCount = rows[0].count;
                } else {
                    var gCount = 0;
                }
                datacounts.push({
                    "date": gDate,
                    "count": gCount
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
}
res.send(JSON.stringify(datacounts));
```

Comment: Probably, your SQL query is getting an error. If you are getting the count only for one date (as it is in the where clause) you don't need to group by an order by, you only get one row

Comment: no. query is working perfectly

Comment: What does `console.log(rows)` look like in your query function? You might need to update your length check to: `rows[0].length > 0` due to the nature of the default query response model.